# Pass params from view to layout in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a variable in view file, i want pass this to layout file.

I use params like below:

```
$this->params['name'] = 'masoud';
```

I try to print this in layout file:

```
<?= $this->params['name'] ?>
```

I get an error: `Undefined index: name` how cat i fix it?

Comment: This code should work correctly, so you're probably doing something wrong (like setting `$this->params['name']` in a wrong place). I suggest to check if value exist before accessing it (`<?= $this->params['name'] ?? '' ?>`) and do some debugging - maybe you're rendering wrong action/view and this param is not initialized.

Comment: @rob006 Agree. This code should work properly. Also, [`??`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) operator is available as of PHP7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `view` is rendered by a controller, you can do as below.

1. Declare a **public** member in your **controller**

   `public $params;`
2. Assign value in your **view**

   `$this->context->params['name'] = 'masoud';`
3. Now you can use the variable in your **layout**

   `<?= $this->context->params['name'] ?>`

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but nothing is displayed @paul

Comment: @Masoud92m Are you sure that you didn't forget the `context`?

Comment: Curious, I could get the params displayed in my machine. Could please post more code of your controller and view?

Comment: i test it in another controller and works, seems my controller is having troublem, thanks a lot @paul

Comment: @Masoud92m Be careful, you will get an error if you access another controller which do not declare `params` member. So it's better to declare this `params member` in the parent controller. In fact, I suggest that you use the method provided by @rob006 in the comment.